# Is there anyway to get the data connection state of the mobile in the native code of android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, native

Is there anyway of getting the data connection state of the mobile in native code of Android? I know that we can do it with ConnectivityManager in Java.

Is there similar kind of thing in native code of Android? As they started supporting native activity from Gingerbread onwards, do they given for connectivity manager as well.

Please tell me if anyone knows. I tried but I didn't got any thing similar to this in native. The only idea as of now I have is Implementing a class using Connectivity Manager in JAVA and calling those functions from the native.

Thanks & Regards,
SSuman185

Answer (score 0):

check this out:

Setup your listener:

```
    private static class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener{ 
    @Override 
    public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength){ /* Do Stuff */
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
    } 

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
      switch (state) {
      case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
        stateString = "Idle";
        break;
      case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
        stateString = "Off Hook";
        break;
      case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
        stateString = "Ringing " + incomingNumber;
        break;
      }
    }

    @Override 
    public void onCellLocationChanged(CellLocation location) { 
        try
        {
             super.onCellLocationChanged(location); 
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        { }
    }
```

};

then you have to register the listener:

```
public static void Init_DataRelatedStuff(Context ForeignContext)
{
    foreignContext = ForeignContext;
    m_psl = new MyPhoneStateListener();
    m_telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)foreignContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    m_telephonyManager.listen(m_psl, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
    m_telephonyManager.listen(m_psl, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CELL_LOCATION);
    m_telephonyManager.listen(m_psl, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}
```

then now you can get the data state:

```
    public static String getDataState()
{
    int nType = m_telephonyManager.getDataState();
    String value = "UNKNOWN";
    switch(nType)
    {
    case 0://DATA_DISCONNECTED
        value = "DISCONNECTED";
        break;
    case 1://DATA_CONNECTING
        value = "CONNECTING";
        break;
    case 2://DATA_CONNECTED
        value = "CONNECTED";
        break;
    case 3://DATA_SUSPENDED
        value = "SUSPENDED";
        break;
    default:
        value = "UNKNOWN";
        break;
    }
    return value;
}
```

also you need permission in manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```